# How to determine if I could apply panel data methods on my dataset?

Tags: panel-data, missing-data

My panel dataset looks as follows:

- 2000 individuals
- 5 time periods

I do not have observations for some individuals for some periods:

- 500 individuals with no missing data
- 500 individuals with 4 periods of missing data
- 500 individuals with 3 periods of missing data
- 500 individuals with 2 periods of missing data

In addition I have a lot of individual-time period combinations with multiple observations.

Of course, this is not a classical panel data structure. However I would like to apply panel data techniques. Is this feasible?

Comment: Do you have any information on why the data are missing?

Comment: The data misses because there was no event in the corresponding period for the individual. So the data is missing not at random.

Comment: Missingness aside for a moment, why is this not a “classical” panel? You do observe individuals over time, correct? And, by multiple observations per $i$ and $t$, do you mean multiple “outcomes” per person?